# Is there an association for academic managers?

Tags: university, administration, professional-association

I there an international society/association for building a community of academic managers (such as department heads, deans, etc)?

I found [Association of University Administrators](http://www.aua.ac.uk/), but it is for administrators (e.g., directors of offices) rather than academic managers.

Comment: What is the difference between "directors of offices" and "academic managers?" Is "association" code for labor union, or do you mean something else? What is the structure of the university where you work? Are there department deans? Division deans? "Deanlets?" Department chairs who are faculty? Department chairs who are management but have the right of retreat?

Comment: The association you linked to calls itself "the professional association for higher education administration and management." I don't see why this excludes deans or department heads.

Comment: @ff524 it does not exclude deans and department heads, but their focus is on administrative roles rather than academic executives. For instance, I am interested to attend a meeting in which most participants and lectures are about the roles of academic heads, deans, VPs.

Answer (score 1):

The [Association of Deans and Directors](http://www.adandd.org/) might fulfill what you are looking for: it is not clear from their website the degree to which it is international, but there also seems to be nothing that indicates it is not.